# how can i access List. parameter from Method constructor in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to get access from the constructor to a List dot Parameter?

What I want is one function instead of 2 or more
something like this.

```
void somethingA() 
{ someList.where((item) => item.A == "123") }

void somethingB() 
{ someList.where((item) => item.B == "456") }
```

to something like this

```
void something(List list.XY) 
{ someList.where((item) => item.list.XY == "123") }
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a list based on its items :

```
List<List> someList = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]];

  void something(List<List> list){
    list.where((element){
      return element == ["a", "b"];
    });
  }
```

based on its specific item :

```
List<List> somethingB(List<List> list){
    List<List> result = [];
    list.where((element){
      element.map((e){
        if(e == "a"){
          result.add(e);
        }
        if(e == "b"){
          result.add(e);
        }
      }).toList();
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: ok, Thanks I try to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reall pass something like list.XY, but you can come close:

```
Iterable<T> itemsWithValue5<T>(Iterable<T> values, int Function(T) selector) {
  return values.where((value) => selector(value) == 5);
}

void main() {

  const words = ['Hello', 'World'];
  
  final wordsWithLength5 = itemsWithValue5<String>(words, (word) => word.length);
  
  print(wordsWithLength5);
}
```

The `selector` parameter takes a function that gets an item (in this case of type string) and transforms it into something else, in this case an `int`. This allows you to write something like `(word) => word.length` as your selector, which is alreasy pretty close to `list.XY`.